# How do I assign a value for the parameter 'weights' in the dbscan function in R?

Tags: r, cluster-analysis

I am performing a density-based clustering on R. I have automotive part data of 73 parts with 15 metrics. I have used the fgkm function in the wskm package to find weights of each of these 15 metrics. I want to know how i can pass this in the dbscan syntax. The syntax is:

```
dbscan(x, eps, minPts = 5, weights = NULL, borderPoints = TRUE, ...)
```

I have the array of weights in 'a'

```
a<- c(0.12,1,1,0.13,0.12,1,0.13,0.13,0.5,0.49,1,0.13,0.11,1,0.13)
```

But since *weights* has to be a numeric argument, I am confused how to pass this.

```
PL_SL23_dbscan_test<- dbscan(subset23A_copy_norm_test, eps = 3.22, minPts = 4, weights=a)
```

The error I get while running the above is :

> ***Error in dbscan(subset23A_copy_norm_test, eps = 3.22, minPts = 4, weights = a) : 
>     unused arguments (minPts = 4, weights = a)***

Comment: Your error message seems to point to something else,  but there is supposed to be one weight for each data point, not one for each attribute. Your `a` has 15 values,  not 73.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To weight *attributes* simply scale your data accordingly.

The weight parameter is to weight *instances* ("rows") not columns.